# Synchronization of Android Views on top of GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview, glsurfaceview, textureview

Is there a good way to draw standard Android `View` objects on top of a `GLSurfaceView` and synchronize the movement between the two layers?

My layout looks like

```
<FrameLayout>
     <RelativeLayout>
     <MyCustomGLSurfaceView>
</FrameLayout>
```

The `MyCustomGLSurfaceView` implements a camera and this camera is moved when the user touches the screen appropriately.

At the end of the `onDrawFrame()` callback in the renderer I invoke a callback to tell the `RelativeLayout` that the camera has moved and that it should update the location of any subviews as necessary.

To try and synchronize the two layers I am doing the following:

- Set `renderMode = RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY` within `MyCustomGLSurfaceView`
- Having `MyCustomGLSurfaceView` implement `Choreographer.FrameCallback` and in the `doFrame(frameTimeNanos: Long)` method calling `requestRender()`
- onDrawFrame invokes a callback to indicate the camera has moved and the `RelativeLayout` updates the position of it’s subviews as necessary.
- Delaying the position of the camera 1 frame within the `MyCustomGLSurfaceView` since it appears that the Android `View` objects aren't updated on the screen until the following frame whereas the `MyCustomGLSurfaceView` was updated immediately.

The theory is that by listening for `Choreographer` callbacks, the rendering of the `MyCustomGLSurfaceView` is happening at the same time as when the application is re-drawing the standard UI elements.

This seems to work reasonably well but there are noticeable stutters within the Android `View` object layer. Also positioning the elements in the Android `View` layer has some odd behaviour when doing it via setting margins (views get destroyed when they're off screen and don't always reappear and sometimes stop being updated at all). I have tried positioning them using `translationX / translationY` but then the synchronization between the two layers isn't as good.

Is there a good approach for achieving this synchronization?

I have thought that it might be better to use a `TextureView` as opposed to a `GLSurfaceView` since the `TextureView` is composited into the view hierarchy rather than being a separate surface, so I thought maybe synchronization will fall out naturally from that.

Comment: Are you setting up margins using something similar to the method in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view)?    Also recommend looking at [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) (especially Record GL App use of Choreographer).  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317132/minimize-android-glsurfaceview-lag) may be helpful.  Also, [architecture](https://source.android.com/docs/core/graphics/architecture) docs.  Comment cause it doesn't feel like enough for an answer.