# Unity: optimized frame pacing creates a 3 to 4 frames display delay on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, render, delay, display

When I check "optimized frame pacing" settings in my player settings in unity 2019.2.5f1, I notice a 2 to 3 frame delay between when the frame renders and when it is actually displayed on the screen.

It is also randomly tied to the device (tried on two different s9+ and one s7 and they seem to exibit this behaviour, while the S7edge doesnt, despite having the same spec as the s7?)

When I uncheck it, all my device seems to display the frame with a 1 frame delay only.

I have went through a lot of online resources:
 - [this one relates to input lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981947/what-are-the-causes-of-input-touch-display-lag-in-android)
 - [this one is about reducing GLSurfaceView lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317132/minimize-android-glsurfaceview-lag)
 - [optimized Frame pacing documentation](https://developer.android.com/games/sdk/frame-pacing)
 - [graphic architecture](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html)

My questions are:

1. Why is there such a delay between my render of my frames and the display with optimized frame pacing.
2. How to reduce this frame delay consistently to have at most 1 frame display lag

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately not as of today.